# Validation string with apache POI

Tags: java, spring, apache-poi

i need to do a validation, i need to know if the cell c3 there is the String "Numero"

but i get one error:

```
> private int validaLinha(Row row) { String pedidoExcel = “Numero”;
> 
>     Cell teste = row.getCell(new CellReference("C3").getCol());
> 
>     try{
>         if (teste == null || teste.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK)
>             return 0;
> 
>         if (teste == pedidoExcel)
>             return 1;
> 
>     }catch (Exception e){
>         return -1;
>     }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svtW9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the value of the cell and user equals.
https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html

```
if (pedidoExcel.equals(teste.getStringCellValue()))
             return 1;
```